# Dynamic DB creation

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to address a set of problems here.

I have a need to dynamically create a MYSQL database on RDS services provided by AWS using PHP. Is there any API which could be used to access a sql file present in a directory to dynamically create a db with a set of tables and data present in the sql file much like what could be done using xmlapi in CPanel.

Also, once the DB is created i need to dynamically create and add  a user  to the db created in the first step.

It is more like an individual db for all the users present.

Any help on this?

Comment: This is possible but somewhat unusual. Creating a database can be done via a query just like any other MySQL query, so you can grammatically run that statement. If it's stored in a file in your web server or in another location, you can read the file contents and execute that query like any other one. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I am currently using CPanel and working with XMLAPI's for dynamic db creation. Now i am thinking why not go with a RDS on cloud. Could be more effective and easy to use. I know it can be done using mysql queries but i was wondering if there is a way to create it using api's.